# Blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) : Angular 8 deployed on tomcat 9.0.30 fails to serve the assets

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, angular8, tomcat9

I have a project in which the user interface is based on angular 8 and the backend is a springboot java service. The entire project is a multi module project with the angular part being a separate module with `front-end builder` being used to build the angular code into a single executable jar. The application runs fine when the embedded tomcat is used. I have a new requirement to try and deploy the angular ui part separately on an external tomcat . But when i copy the dist folder to the webapps folder and try to serve it , the browser blocks the request saying :

```
Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/polyfills-es2015.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

[image: browser screenshot]

After doing some google search I came to understand that the issue occurs because angular 8 cli fails to add the `type` attribute to the `script` tag in `index.html` . When i manually add the type,everything works fine. Can anyone please help me to understand why this is happening, and also a possible fix for the issue other than manual editing.

Generated `index.html` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Application</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>

</html>
```

So, to summarize everything that works , it's as follows :

- The type attribute is no longer mandatory in HTML5, hence angular cli no longer adds it as an attribute. In embedded tomcat , the assets were being copied to the `ROOT` which works perfectly as , when I deployed in external tomcat ,I kept the assets under a folder in webapps which meant I had to amend the `baseHref` field (either during build using command or after build manually) to reflect the same.
  The following works :
- Keeping the assets under ROOT folder in webapps (everything works perfectly because the js files are now under the root / ).
- Keeping the files under a folder say for instance `MyApp` and specifying that as  `baseHref` in `index.html` .

Related [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325)

Comment: Seems like the server thinks the JS file is a HTML file...

Comment: I encountered this b/c my browser was trying to get a non-existent js file due to some cache issue. A simple CTRL+SHIFT+R fixed it.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am seeing the same issue after upgrading from angular 7 to angular 8.

Comment: @Andrew The issue that I faced got resolved with the accepted answer, a summary of which I have added to the question itself.

Comment: I upvoted "Stack Underflow" because his/her comment about "non-existent js file" pointed me in the right direction.  I was running into a similar problem caused by a misnamed js file.  The main takeaway for me is that you will get this confusing mime type error if the file is not found.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
 <base href="/">
```

is the issue , change it to your context root . Or change it to

```
<base href=".">
```

Browser is unable to find your JS file because it looks for JS file relative to base href.

Your base href= "/" , so it looks for all js file in the in "localhost:8080/",
but your JS files might have present in "localhost:8080/someRoot"

One more solution you can think of is, deploying in the ROOT folder of tomcat with out context root , if that is allowed for your project

Comment: Then why does it work when i add the type="text/javascript" to the index.html script tags ? Also, I have  no issue in serving this from an embedded tomcat .

Comment: Do you have Js file in this location ? "http://localhost:8080/polyfills-es2015.js" that means do you have js directly in your webapps folder ?

Comment: Embedded tomcat might have deployed the project in ROOT folder.
Please note that type="text/javascript" is optional in HTML5,
 your code should work event if it doesn't have "text/javascript"

Comment: I have added it to the ROOT  of tomcat.

Comment: But it was not working when it was being served from another folder. I think you are right , keeping it in ROOT works.

Comment: This also happens with Angular 11, using ng serve on a non-root path

Comment: already have the same problem even if <base href="."> is well set , what workaround possible to that ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa in my case it was due to my module was in a relative path and I didn't add the '.js' to the file. So it worked with '../../my_dir/my_module.js'

Comment: which file contains this things " <base href="/">" . where i have to change this things?

Answer (score 53):

I had this issue trouble me for a while. For those of you like me who weren't careful, make sure you have the `.js` at the end of the file name in the import.

Comment: So for `dotenv`, I do this: `import dotenv from "./node_modules/dotenv"`. Isn't that correct? `import dotenv from "./node_modules/dotenv.js"` doesn't exist

Answer (score 12):

The server thinks that your JS file is a HTML file.

This may be because the server-side recognition is buggy or the JS file is non-existent (and the server does not send a 404 status code?) or there is no js in it.

Because of that, it sends the Content-Type `text/html`.

The browser sees the content type, thinks this is no css and does not allow it.

If you specify the type(client side) or change the type server-side, it should work.

Comment: Yes i have tried manually adding the type in index.html at server side and it works as i have said in the question. But why is angular cli not adding it during ng build ?

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with the automatical recognition of the file

Comment: That's it in my case. My IDE automatically omitted the `.js` file extension when I created the import statement. Adding `.js` to `import { thing } from './file.js';` did the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by "specify the type(client side) or change the type server-side".

Comment: @meropis The content-type could be changed client-side with `type="text/html"` or server-side by sending a different `Content-Type` header back in the response.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason is that the Vite bundler (Rollup?) sets the script file as an absolute path `"/assets/index123.js"` instead of relative `"./assets/index123.js"` in the `index.html` file

Comment: What did you do to solve it?

Comment: I went into the generated `index.html` file under the `/dist` folder and put a period in there and it worked.

Comment: For // vite.config.js
`export default {
    base: '/project-name/',
  }`

And then specifying relative paths in my js worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the `.js` in your import statement.

For me, I relied on VS Code to autopopulate the import for my `./add.js` file, for which it wrote:

```js
import { add } from "./add";
```

And I saw the error in Firefox.

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/add” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

Once I added the `.js` to make it:

```js
import { add } from "./add.js";
```

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution it worked for my vanilla JS project

Problem Desc: The browser is not able to find the files you want, thus sends you a 404 HTML page as response to your script request (waits for a js, but gets some html instead)

1. the import must have type="module"
   ex: `<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>`
2. All the imports must finish whit .js
   ex: `import characterData from "./modules/data.js";`
3. If still doesn't work, remove all th imports and write it again (helps more in VSCode)
4. If somehow still breaks, keep the `main.js` in the root folder and add all the other to a new `modules` folder

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things have helped me during my learning phase of Typescript ES6 to solve the above error:

1. Add .js at the end of the import statement. For e.g.:
   `import {testModule} from './Classes.js';`
2. In the index.html file, change the script type to "module" instead of "text/javascript".
3. In `tsconfig.json` comment out `"module": "commonjs"` and replace it with `"target": "ES6"`.
4. Delete all the files from your JS output folder and recompile the typescript to generate those files again.