# Getting Typescript error TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'

Tags: typescript

I am doing a type script project . Here is my code snapshot , After run this project , I have found bellow error.

class : Address.ts

```
export class Address {
    public Street1: string = "mywork";
}
exports.Address = Address;
```

class : script.ts

```
import { Address } from "./Address";

class Customer {
  private _customerName = "";
  public addressobj: Address = new Address();

  public set CustomerName(name: string) {
    if (name.length == 0) {
      throw ("name is misssing");
    }
    this._customerName = name;
  }

  public get CustomerName(): string {
    return this._customerName;
  }

  getFullName(): string {

    alert(this.addressobj.Street1);
    return this._customerName;
  }

}
```

html file : index.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<script type="module" src="src/script.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>hello word masum</h1>
  <script>

    try {
      var cs = new Customer();
      cs.CustomerName = "sudia";
      alert(cs.getFullName());

    } catch (ex) {
      alert(ex);
    }


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have found bellow error : Address.ts:4:1 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'exports'.

How can i resolve this "exports"  error ?

[image]

Comment: Because it is export, as at top of your code.

Comment: Yes, It is export . so , how can resolve this export missing  ?

Comment: Just remove the "exports.Address = Address;" and it should work, you are already exporting it.

Comment: Yes, After remove , this exports error is overcome but it gives another error in browser console .  ERROR: Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/script.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925804/blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text-html-angular-8-deployed-on

Comment: It's just an html tag in the head of page https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: after solve this issue got another issue : Loading failed for the module with source “http://127.0.0.1:5500/out/Address”.