# Angular production build can't load - Loading module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, ng-build

I built my application running ng build --configuration=production and uploaded it (manually via FTP) to a server (I tried two different ones). Accessing the root like myurl.com works fine, but whenever I want to directly access a subpage, for example, myurl.com/subpage the page is blank and I get the following error:
`Loading module from “https://myurl.com/runtime-es2015.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).` Same error for also for polyfills-es2015.js, main-es2015.js

If I access the root and navigate to the subpage everything works fine.

Until now I tried to:

- set `<base href=".">` in index.html
- set `"target": "es5"` in tsconfig.json
- manually change the type of the scripts from `type="module"` to `type="text/javascript"`
  like here: `<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="text/javascript">`

Angular CLI & Angular Version `8.1`

Typescript version `3.4.5`

Webpack version `4.35.2`

On the server, I also have a .htaccess file which was needed, as otherwise accessing myurl.com/subpage resulted in a 404

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would be really thankful, if somebody could help me.

**Edit**
Accessing the "subpage" during ng serve works fine!

**Edit2**
When inspecting the Network tab in the development console on the browser, the GET requests for the .js files work fine, but the type is wrong (html).
If I load the root page (myurl.com) the mime-type is correct.

Comment: I had the same issue, I have mentioned how I resolved it. There is a similar post. Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62226117/12080473 sometimes the error message in the console misleads the actual cause of the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with an Angular app I deployed to `https://host.my/app`.  As mentioned in [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576343/3079262) changing the

`<base href="/">`

to

**`<base href="./">`**

solved it for me.  Just setting it to `<base href=".">` did not.

HTH